# Nested properties enigma in Stripes

Tags: java, hibernate, properties, nested, stripes

I have these model (POJO)

```
class Participant {
     String partid;

     //getter setter
     //and other old plain POJO methods
}

class Merchant {
     Participant participant;
     //getter setter
     //and other old plain POJO methods
}

class Terminal {
     Merchant merchant;
     //getter setter
     //and other old plain POJO methods
}
```

and a control-view class with filtering just like this

```
 ListTerminal implement ActionBean {
      ...
      Terminal terminal;
      //getter setter
      ...
 }
```

then on .jsp i'd wrote something like this

list_terminal.jsp

```
...
<td><s:text name="terminal.merchant.participant.partid" /></td>
...
```

but then an error pops out

org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: merchant.participant.partid of: com.hpal.model.Terminal

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a public before your partid. Because the default behaviour of class attributes is to limit access to other classes in the same package.

Or use your getters and setters and put it private.

Comment: the actual codes are much more detail then the ones I'd post. the codes above are only snippet to minimize the effort of explaining the situation. so yes, the modifiers (public, private) are already set